# Exporting Vector Layer with OGR2Layers Plugin?

Tags: openlayers-2, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I'm using QGIS 2.0 Dufour on my Linux (Ubuntu 12.10).I'm download shapefile
of Croatia country from this site (http://www.gadm.org/country) and i added a new vector layer where i created some polygons. (a picture is attached).
When i created OpenLayers HTML map using OGR2 layer plugin, desired polygons are not displayed in open street map.

Where am I wrong, if it is even possible?

[Vector layer in QGIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwTNr.png)

Answer (score 3):

It works for me this way:

- Convert the data to EPSG:3857 using `Rightclick -> Save As ...` (**not** using Set CRS for layer!!!) add that to the canvas and remove the EPSG:4326 layer
- remove extra characters like +-/() and blanks from the layer name (javascript does not like them)
- in the plugin menu, `Openlayers` tab, set Map size to full screen and click on the checkbox at the bottom
- in the `Options` tab, click all check boxes, and `default OpenLayers renderer`

If it still does not work, look into your browsers error console for hints.

Comment: In order to make this work, I had to set the Project CRS to the same as the layer (EPSG:4326). Once I figured that out, it opened perfectly in the viewer.

Comment: Oops. EPSG in comment above should read EPSG:3857. Can only edit within 5 minutes, though.

Comment: Thank you, Andre Joost, this works fine :) , it opened perfectly in the viewer.

Comment: @Llaves: You can delete your comments any time if you made a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

OGR2Layers requires the layer to be publicly assessible like a WMS/WFS server. If you have loaded a local shapefile from your computer, then it will not be assessible from the browser, hence it will not show up.

Answer (score 1):

The map might not show up because of the name of your file. You need to make sure that you have no spaces in the file name, same in the label of your columns. Hope that helps.